# NavigationView with ExpandableListView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, expandablelistview

I have a problem within my `NavigationView`.

I created the view from the standard forms in Android Studio and then changed it so that it looks as i want , but i have 2 problems.

While working on it i saw that i cannot use the standard menu items because i need custom layouts in my menu items. So i implemented that as `ExpandableListView`.

- When i expand the `ExpandableListView` (quite standard with own
  adapter) the image blow is overlapping my list items.
- The second issue is that if i expand all, but not all child are shown
  and the scrolling doesn't work.

Does someone have a hint how i can accomplish this ?

**Here's my code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_dash_board"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"

        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dash_board">
        <!--app:menu="@menu/activity_dash_board_drawer">-->



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/navigationmenu"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="192dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:groupIndicator="@null"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="false">

            </ExpandableListView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_logo"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
            android:contentDescription="@string/its_just_a_logo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo" />

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: Picture of The Navigationview with some Sample items and expanded last group]

Comment: Please share screenshot of that...if possible

Comment: try to attach screenshot so others get better idea!

Comment: The `NavigationView` scrolls on it's own, and is interfering with your `ExpandableListView`. If you're not using the `NavigationView`'s menu, then there's really no need to use a `NavigationView` at all. Remove it, and just use the vertical `LinearLayout` as the drawer, placing the header layout, the `ExpandableListView`, and the `ImageView` all inside it. Be sure to move the `layout_gravity="start"` attribute to the `LinearLayout`, set its `layout_width` to an exact measure - e.g., `240dp` - and set the `ExpandableListView`'s `layout_height` to `0dp`, and its `layout_weight` to `1`.